# What is use of redefining structure that was passed as an argument in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am working with a framework where structures are defined with underscore first and then structure that is used is created as pointer to that internal structure.
Passing it as argument require additional steps of defining local pointer within the function first.
What is use of this comparing with just declaring structure and using it directly?

```
//.h
 typedef struct _tFoo
    {
       int value;
    } _tFoo;
    
    typedef _tFoo* tFoo;

//.c
void    tFoo_setFoo(tFoo* const f, int value)
{
    _tFoo* foo = *f;
    foo->value = value;
}
```

What is benefit of having code above comparing with

```
//.h
 typedef struct _tFoo
    {
       int value;
    } tFoo;
    

//.c
void    tFoo_setFoo(tFoo* const f, int value)
{
    f->value = value;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in C requires you to use an extra level of indirection (pointer). There is no advantage if there is no need. Is some project or class assignment requiring this?

Comment: `_tFoo* foo = *foo;` is wrong; did you mean `_tFoo* foo = *f;`?

Comment: Also, be aware that, in the C grammar, `tFoo* x` is parsed as `tFoo *x`. That is, the `*` and `x` are bound together as a *declarator*, separately from the type specifier `tFoo`. Writing `tFoo* x` misleads the reader as to what the underlying meaning truly is, and `tFoo* x, y` will declare `x` and `y` to be different things (`x` will be a `tFoo *`, but `y` will be a `tFoo`).

Comment: Note that the second version takes a pointer to a `struct _tFoo` whereas the first version takes a pointer-to-pointer, and that changes how the function would be called.  That said, `typedef`ing pointers makes my head hurt and is generally a bad practice, and whoever thought that making `tFoo` a pointer type and `_tFoo` the pointee type deserves a very stern ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, I didn't know that. Fixed examples to `_tFoo* foo = *f;`

Comment: In the first version, `f` is a pointer to a pointer, which makes no sense.  It should have one level of pointer.  Part of the reason for this is that `tFoo` hides a level of indirection, making it look like there's a single level of indirection when in fact there are two.

Comment: That kind of defining typedef pointers to a struct is all around in this code:
[https://github.com/spiricom/LEAF/](https://github.com/spiricom/LEAF/)

Im forking it and trying to understand whether I should keep to that style, or just get rid of it since I don't understand what would be the benefit

Comment: Just use the second version.  You can even get rid of the structure tag `_tFoo`.  Structure tags are rarely needed.  They only come up when you need to declare a pointer to a structure before the structure has been defined.

Comment: I looked at https://github.com/spiricom/LEAF/blob/master/leaf/Src/leaf-delay.c as real example. I think that the author converted code from an object oriented language. In that original OO language, tDely would have been and object and all functions are prefixed by `tDelay_` would have been object's methods: the all takes the first argument similar to the hidden parameter `this` or `self` in object methods. You ask: what is the benefit: more or less conversion from object oriented language to C. Maybe done automatically by a transpiler.

Comment: Reading the readme confirmed what I just said: "We call the psuedo-objects in LEAF "objects" because it's simpler to say, even though technically they are just structs with associated functions. Objects types start with a lowercase t: like tCycle, tSawtooth, tRamp, tEnvelopeFollower......"